# Terraform - How to restrict an input variable to a list of possible choices

Tags: terraform

I have a variable that the user will input during run time. Let's say the variable name is region. However, I want the execution to be only successful if the user picks a value from one of the values defined in a list/ choices.

how can I restrict it so the user's selection has to match values  that are considered acceptable in the variable definition?

Comment: You could try the technique detailed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256780/866021

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terraform - Specifying multiple possible values for Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54254524/terraform-specifying-multiple-possible-values-for-variables)

Comment: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25283

Answer (score 83):

Stumbled across this question.

Since v0.13.0 input validation has been possible directly via the input variables. Thus you can actually achieve this with a snippet such as below.

```
variable "test_variable" {
  type        = string
  description = "some test value"

  validation {
    condition     = contains(["item1", "item2", "item3"], var.test_variable)
    error_message = "Valid values for var: test_variable are (item1, item2, item3)."
  } 
}
```

Read more here - https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/custom-variable-validation-in-terraform-0-13

Comment: Did this answer your Q. Perhaps select it as the official answer?

Comment: AFAIK, this will cause a validation error with `The validation error message must be at least one full sentence starting with an uppercase letter and ending with a period or question mark.` By adding a `.` to the end of the `error_message` string, it should fix it.

Comment: You are correct, sir. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is still is a valid situation that many Terraform users might face. Therefore, I will provide a more up to date answer.

In order to restrict an input variable to a list of possible choices you can now do the following:

```
variable "create_mode" {
  type = string
  description = "Some description"
  default = "Default"

  validation {
    condition = contains(["Default", "PointInTimeRestore", "Replica"], var.create_mode)
    error_message = "Valid values for create_mode are (Default, PointInTimeRestore, Replica)"
  }
}
```

In the example above I have the variable `create_mode`. The valid options are: "Default", "PointInTimeRestore", "Replica". So in order to restrict the input I'm adding the validation block which contains the condition and the error message to display in case somebody tries to use an invalid value for the variable.

Now if I try to initiatiate this variable to let's say `create_mode = "Random"` I will get the following error when I do `terraform plan` or `terraform validate`.

```
daniel:~$tfplan
╷
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 91, in module "pg_fs_database":
│   91:   create_mode = "Random"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.create_mode is "Random"
│ 
│ Valid values for create_mode are (Default, PointInTimeRestore, Replica)
│ 
│ This was checked by the validation rule at ../postgresql-flexible-server/variables.tf:56,3-13.
```

Have a look [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/configuration-language/custom-conditions) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

One solution:

```
variable "values_list" {
  description = "acceptable values"
  type = "list"
  default = ["true", "false"]
}

variable "somevar" {
description = "must be true or false"
}

resource "null_resource" "is_variable_value_valid" {
  count = "${contains(var.values_list, var.somevar) == true ? 0 : 1}"
  "ERROR: The somevar value can only be: true or false" = true
}
```

If you pass a value different than "true" or "false" for the "somevar" variable, Terraform will throw an error and stop. The disadvantage is that you have to list all values in the `default` block of `values_list`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256780/1364793

Comment: Upgrading into 0.13 will offer an elegant solution with custom validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform currently has no first-class feature for this, but you can achieve the desired effect (albeit with a less-helpful error message) by asking Terraform to look the value up in a map:

```
variable "example" {
  description = "must be a, b, or c"
}

locals {
  allowed_example_values = { for v in ["a", "b", "c"] : v => v }

  checked_example = local.allowed_example_values[var.example] # will fail if var.example is invalid
}
```

Because the values in the `allowed_example_values` map are the same as the keys, you can then use `local.checked_example` in place of `var.example` everywhere else in the module to set up the dependency graph such that it's impossible for an invalid value to be used.

Some caveats/limitations:

- You can't customize the error message that Terraform will return when the value is invalid. Instead, Terraform will return the generic error about the key not matching any element in the map. However, it will include the source code snippet from the affected line in the error message (in Terraform 0.12 or later) so the comment at the end of that line should be visible in the error message and thus provide an additional clue to the user as to what might be wrong.
- This works fully only for string values, because map keys are always strings in Terraform. Using other primitive types can work as a result of Terraform's automatic conversions from bool and number to string, but you should be sure to explicitly declare the type of the variable (using e.g. `type = number`) to ensure that Terraform will normalize incoming values into the expected type before looking them up in the map. This technique will not work at all for collection and structural types.
- I wouldn't suggest using strings `"true"` and `"false"` since Terraform has a `bool` type which can represent that more intuitively. If you are using Terraform 0.11 and earlier then it's not possible to *constrain* to bool, but in Terraform 0.12 and later you can declare a variable as `type = bool` and then Terraform will handle the validation automatically.

Comment: I think you're missing a `local.` before the `allowed_example_values[var.example]`, i.e. `local.allowed_example_values[var.example]` (at least it didn't work for me using terraform v0.12.13 otherwise)

Comment: You're right! Thanks, @burnedikt. I've edited the example.